# Update windows 8 to windows 10 and xampp stopped

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, windows-10

I just updated windows 8 to windows 10 XAMPP server is stopped working.
It starts apache and mysql but not showing anything in browser.

Comment: Update xampp or install it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XAMPP official site's [Windows FAQ](https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_windows.html) has a section (How can I get XAMPP working on port 80 under Windows 10?) which indicates that "by default, Windows 10 starts Microsoft IIS on port 80" and provides instructions on disabling it.